# How to write not_if to check for directory or file permission

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

The below script runs every time I run my cookbook:

```
execute 'Change group ownership tomcat' do
   command 'chown -R tomcat.admin /usr/private/tomcat'
end
```

Can someone advise how to write a `not_if` or something that prevents this code from executing if ownership is `tomcat.admin`?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great option here. Writing the code for this would be more tricky than it it probably worth. I would just let it run every time unless you really need to fix this :( This is on my list to fix at some point, but the short version would be to use `Dir#[]` or similar to get a list of every file/directory entry and then use the `File.stat` interface on Unix and similar APIs on Windows to check each thing in there. But again, just let it run and worry about another thing :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good practice. Use the *directory* resource. If it already exists, the definition will update ownership only.

```
directory '/usr/private/tomcat' do
  owner 'tomcat'
  group 'admin'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
```

Definitely more elegant that using execute.

Comment: That will only update the owner/mode on the directory itself, not everything inside it too.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Find to Filter Files

An easy way to do what you want is by using the *find* utility's `-exec` flag to manage permissions for just the files and directories that need to be changed. The following finds all files that are not owned by either *tomcat* or the *admin* group, and then passes only the list of files to be changed on to the *chown* command.

```
execute 'chown tomcat files' do
  command 'find /usr/private/tomcat \
           ! -user tomcat -or ! -group admin \
           -exec chown tomcat:admin {} +'
end
```

This may or may not be faster than simply recursively chowning the entire tree without inspecting the permissions first. A lot depends on the implementation of *chmod* and the amount of filesystem I/O generated on your particular system, but using *find* should cut down on filesystem writes, especially if you've set `NOATIME` on the filesystem.